# How to make a console c++ text game that uses pdCurses portable

Tags: text, console, portability, transfer, pdcurses

Hey so i've made a text game using the pdCurses library and microsoft opperating system tools and i would like to make it work on any computer. Here are my includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h> // or "ctime"
#include <stdio.h> // for 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <Windows.h> 
#include <conio.h>
#include<curses.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>

#include <myStopwatch.h> // for keeping times
#include <myMath.h>      // numb_digits() and digit_val();
```

myStopwath/Math.h includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

**Do i need to make some kind of installer wizard like most downloadable programs? Can i simply throw the dlls, libs, and headers in a folder? or is there a much simpler way for such a small program? Thanks! =)**

BTW: all i want to be able to do is show someone my game from another computer, not being chained to this computer only and msVS++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, I suppose you want... let's call it "deployability" rather portability, which usually refers to the ability to run a program across different platforms.

Looking at your includes, everything saves PDCurses should be included in a standard Windows install (although if you use a particularly new version of the VC++ compiler, you might not get it to work on older Windows). For PDCurses, if it provides its DLL, you can place it side by side with the .exe and it should work. Alternatively, look into static linking, which will embed a copy of the library inside your executable.

To be 100% sure, you can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) to check exactly which DLLs your program depend on, cross-check with the internet and bundle whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using pdcurses as your library is a step in the right direction, because it is cross-platform.  However, `Windows.h` and `conio.h` (and their associated libraries) are not cross-platform.  Much of the functionality of conio can probably be found in pdcurses.

Whether you can find compatible libraries for the functions in `Windows.h` will depend on what functions you are using and what platform you are looking to target.  The other alternative is to use a host of `#ifdef` statements to include what you need for each platform.

The rest of those headers are a part of the C++ or the C standard libraries, so those should be portable.

**Edit:**
Thanks for clarifying your objective.  I had initially thought you wanted to use it across multiple platforms.  In the case that you describe, you need to make sure that you have all of the necessary .dlls with the application, or that you have linked everything statically (the other answer tells you a bit more about both of those).  If necessary, test your program and dlls out on a virtual machine or a clean Windows install on another box.

Comment: I mean if i want to simply make the executable work on another computer... I want to be able to sow someone my game without having to play it in msVS++ on this computer only! Do i need to place the dll files in a folder or something?

Comment: Hi Griffin, if you want this to run this on Mac or Linux (cross platform) you cannot rely on dll files... For a simple curses based game, you should not need to have any other file, but the compiled executable, Windows, Linux, OR Mac. I have written a few games like these and that was my experience.